# Pull down to show div in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

What would be the best way to achieve a snapchat like feature in a web application built with AngularJS. When the user scrolls down / pulls the screen down, a div appears. When the user scrolls back up the div gets pushed back up.

This would be something like the snapchat swipe to refresh feature but the div stays there till the user doesn't scroll back up.

Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide a sample of your code so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
inout='in', win = $(window);
win.scroll(function(){
  $('#msg').html( win.scrollTop() );
  
  if ( win.scrollTop() > 200 && inout=='in'){
    $('#slideOut').animate({
        left : 0
    },500);
    inout = 'out';
  }
  if (win.scrollTop() < 200 && inout=='out'){
    $('#slideOut').animate({
        left : '-100%'
    },500);
    inout = 'in';
  }
  
}); //END win.scroll
```

```css
#wrap{height:2000px;}
#slideOut{position:fixed;top:80px;left:-100%;padding:50px;background:wheat;}
#msg{position:fixed;top:50px;right:10px;padding:20px;background:palegreen;border:1px solid green;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideOut">This div slides out</div>
<div id="wrap">
  Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here. 
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```